# Frameworks/API that uses quantum computer?

Tags: api, frameworks, quantum-computing

Are there any framework that allows to create software or apps that uses the quantum computer, asides from Q#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [list of open-source quantum software projects](https://github.com/markf94/os_quantum_software) on GitHub which includes an overview of actively developed quantum programming languages and frameworks. It is actively maintained, reflecting appearance of new languages and tools.